# Importing array from PHPExcel producing array to string error

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I am trying to populate a table in php from an imported array using PHPExcel. I am getting the 'producing array to string error in' error. I believe it has to do with converting the array to string. The error says its from the line with `mysqli_stmt_execute($query_mtcelogARRAY);`

```php
$mtcelogARRAY = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2)->rangeToArray('A8:A18');
$num_mtcelog = count($mtcelogARRAY);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet
$mtcelogID = $siteNAME.'.'.$Maindate.'.';
for( $i=0; $i<=$num_mtcelog; $i++ ){
    $sql_mtcelog = "INSERT INTO `maintenance_log`(`mtcelogID`,`mtcelogTYPE`,`MaintenanceID`) VALUES (?,?,?)"; 
    $query_mtcelogARRAY = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql_mtcelog);                  
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query_mtcelogARRAY,"sss", $mtcelogID, $mtcelogARRAY[$i], $MaintenanceID);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($query_mtcelogARRAY);
    mysqli_stmt_close($query_mtcelogARRAY);
}
var_dump($mtcelogARRAY);
```

This is how it populates my table

[image]

And my array look like this

[image]

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query_mtcelogARRAY,"sss", $mtcelogID, $mtcelogARRAY[$i], $MaintenanceID);
```

to

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query_mtcelogARRAY,"sss", $mtcelogID, $mtcelogARRAY[$i][0], $MaintenanceID);
```